# Java: Generating a random 3 digit number using a for loop

Tags: java

I need to generate a random 3 digit number using a for loop for a project but am completely stuck. Here is what i have.

```
    for(int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++){
        randNum = r.nextInt(9 - 9 + 1) + 9;
        System.out.println(singleNum1);
    }
```

I know how to generally use a for loop, just not for generating a number. And each number has to be seperated, and then pieced together. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Define "completely stuck".

Comment: How would you obtain random digits, i.e. integers in 0-9 range, remembering that [java.util.Random.nextInt(n)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/random_nextint_inc_exc.htm) is inclusive of 0 and exclusive of `n`??

Comment: hint: r.nextInt(9-9+1) is the same as r.nextInt(1), which will always return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this differently but the main message here is to check out the methods you're using and the way they are working before starting coding with them.

If the use of methods is complicated, use simple algorithms and then try optimizing them.

Here is a method :

```
    Random r = new Random();
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
        output+=r.nextInt(10);
    }
    int outputInt = Integer.parseInt(output);
```

Here is a second one :

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int output = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
        output+=(r.nextInt(10)*Math.pow(10, i));
    }
    System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I didn't know how to get a a new number each time the loop passed. And now i know about the "variable"+= Thanks again.